# The 'ratio' of a 2x2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Define the 'ratio' of a 2x2 matrix $$A= \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{pmatrix} $$

to be $\frac{b}{c}$ when $c\neq 0$. Show that the ratio of $A^n$ is equal to the ratio of $A$, when the ratio of $A^n$ is well-defined.

My instinct is to go with a proof by induction, but I really can't see a way to prove this.

Comment: There is no reason that the "ratio" of $A^n$ is well-defined. The left-bottom coefficient can become $0$.

Comment: I think the question should read "the ratio of $A^n$ is equal to the ratio of $A$ if it is well-defined". Where did the problem come from?

Comment: @RobArthan edited to reflect your comments, thank you. Came from a set of interview prep questions I was given a few years ago, but no one I knew could answer it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Theorem**

There are $x_n$ such that
$$ A_n :=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_n & b x_n \\
c x_n & d_n
\end{pmatrix}
= A^n
$$

**Proof by induction**

For $n=1$ it is trivial: $x_1 := 1$.

Let the theorem be true for a $n$.

Then on the one hand
$$ A^{n+1} = A^n
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_n & b x_n \\
c x_n & d_n
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
aa_n + cbx_n & b(a_n + dx_n) \\
c (d_n + ax_n) & dd_n + bcx_n
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

On the other hand
$$ A^{n+1} =
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
A^n
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
a_n & b x_n \\
c x_n & d_n
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
aa_n + cbx_n & b(d_n + ax_n) \\
c (a_n + dx_n) & dd_n + bcx_n
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Thus $a_n + dx_n = d_n + ax_n =: x_{n+1}$. $\square$

Comment: Just a note: $x_n = \frac{\lambda_1^n-\lambda_2^n}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}$ for $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$ and $x_n = n\lambda_1^{n-1}$ for $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2.$ $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of $A.$

Answer (score 2):

In the sense of the above definition the matrix

$$A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

has ratio $=0$. Since $A^2=0$, the ratio for $A^2$ is not defined.

It seems, that "ratio" is not a good definition.

Comment: However, at least for $n = 2$ and $n = 3$, the conjecture is true if you qualify it by adding "when the 'ratio' of $A^n$ is well-defined". So I think the question is interesting.

Comment: @Fred thank you, edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Diagonalize the matrix.
If it can be diagonalized, you get $A =PDP^{-1}$.  The ratio depends on $P$, not on the diagonal matrix $D$.  All powers of $A$ use the same $P$.
If it can't be diagonalized, then $D$ becomes an upper triangular matrix with equal numbers on the diagonal, and again the ratio is independent of $D$